# How would I make a help command that grabs them instead manually?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a help command that when you use it, instead of having to manually type all the commands, how would I do that? like if I do !help utility how would I grab the utility folder and then get all the commands and list it? i've been trying fs but its confusing with how you would get directs. any help?

Comment: Please read [ask] and try to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with using `fs`

```js
const fs = require('fs')

// check if that folder exists
if (!fs.existsSync(`../../commands/${args[0]}`))
 return message.channel.send('That folder does not exist');

// make array of all files within this folder
const files = fs.readdirSync(`../../commands/${args[0]})

for (const file of files) {
  const command = require(`../../commands/${args[0]}/${file}`) // require the file

  // now you can do whatever you want with it!
  console.log(command.name, command.desription)
};
```

Comment: I'm trying to look for one that gets all the commands.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Are you using a `client.commands` collection as a command handlre?